# open a window on top of another window in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I would like to have a button on the aspx form (using vb.net)
The button would open a smaller form, with some text explaining what needs to be completed.
Does someone have sample code on how to do this?

I want the new window to simply popup in front of the current window.
Thank you

Comment: Instead of a popup, I would recommend using a modal instead: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript `window.open` method to bring a new window.

```
var mywindow = window.open("myhelpPage.html, '', 'status=1,width=700,
                           height=600,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,top=10,left=200');
```

This will open a new window. If you want any fancy model popup, there are a lot of javascript plugins out there which does this. I have used [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) and [jQModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/). plugins( this requires jQuery library in your page)

Answer (score 0):

There are many options for this. You could include jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) and create a dialog box like so:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
     $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```